# How to write a tag?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I have one `CommonVO` interface contains id,my child Vo `EmployeeVO` implements `CommonVO` interface.

`EmployeeVO` Contains `Empid`,`EmpName`.

I am adding `EmployeeVo` to `ArrayList` object. Finally i am passing this `ArrayList` object to jsp page.

So here my question is: how to retrieve `EmployeeVo` values , With custom tag. I know i can retrieve this by JSTL, but here i want to write my Own.

Can anyone tell me , how to write custom tag for this.

Comment: If you can do it with JSTL, why bother writing a custom tag?:

Comment: Look in the source of `c:forEach`.

Comment: skaffman:Original list Contains EmployeeVO objects,Based on my requirement i am type casting it to CommonVO to get the id.CommonVO temp=(CommonVO)list.get(i).After modifying that list i returned this list object to jsp page to retrieve all the properties of employee.I think we can't achieve this with JSTL right?

Comment: Baluc:your blogs are very good,I dont know  what i have to look,can you give me breif explaination

Answer (score 0):

> Based on my requirement i am type casting it to CommonVO to get the id.CommonVO temp=(CommonVO)list.get(i).After modifying that list i returned this list object to jsp page to retrieve all the properties of employee.I think we can't achieve this with JSTL right?

You don't need to cast it in EL. It attempts to access the method by reflection, then the runtime type don't matter anyway. The JSTL `c:forEach` will just work.

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee">
        <tr>
            <td>${employee.empid}</td>
            <td>${employee.empName}</td>
         </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Unrelated to the problem, I wonder how useful it's to have a `CommonVO`.

Comment: Baluc: In commonvo i have id filed,I am implementing this interfae in EmployeeVo,so implemented that id method in employee vo to get the id of employee.Because i have common functionality to retrive id's from different vo's.So iam perparing list object that contains commonvo.So here i want to retrieve employee fields in my jsp page.Is above answer work with if i have only list of employee objects right?